# Issues with Quick Sort List Java

Tags: java, sorting, quicksort

I am working on a program for my AP Computer Science Class (I am brand new to programming). I wrote a quick sort method, but it is not sorting correctly and I cannot find my problem. This is my code. The output results in the list with a few values moved around, but not in the correct order. I am trying to sort a list of students based off of their grades. getScore() accesses the student's score that I am sorting based off of.

```
public static void quickSort(List<Student> b) {
  int left = 0, right = b.size()-1;
  if (left >= right) return;
  int i = left;
  int j = right;
  int pivotValue = b.get((left+right) / 2).getScore();
  while (i < j) {
      while (b.get(i).getScore() < pivotValue) i++;
          while (pivotValue < b.get(j).getScore()) j--;
              if (i <= j) {
              Student temp = b.get(i);
              b.set(i, b.get(j));
              b.set(j, temp);
              i++;
              j--;
          }
      }
  }  
}
```

All help is greatly appreciated. In getting the code to work.

Comment: please provide sample input and output